# Changing screen brightness with keys doesn't work on clevo based laptop

Tags: debian, gnome, intel-graphics, brightness, backlight

So I've got Debian with GNOME on my [Clevo](https://www.xoticpc.com/custom-gaming-laptops-notebooks-gaming-laptops-ct-118-96-98/custom-gaming-laptops-notebooks-clevo-sager-notebooks-ct-95-51-162.html) N85_87HP6 laptop with a GTX1060 video display adapter plus Intel's integrated GPU. Pressing `fn + f8/f9`doesn't change my screen's brightness. I've tried using

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi = acpi_backlight=intel"
```

and a few other lines like that in my grub file, including [a tip](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/clevo-laptop-lcd-and-keyboard-backlight/39028/16) to add `i915.enable_dpcd_backlight`, but none helped.

Commands like

```
 # tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness <<< 100
```

and 
`xbacklight -dec 10`
work but I'm unable to make my keys work. I've been digging around the internet since yesterday but I didn't found any solution to my problem.
I've also noticed with 
`xev` that when I press `fn + f8/f9` nothing is detected, but when I press `fn + f5/f6` that are keys responsible for sound volume it detects them normally.

I've also tried making a `20-intel.conf` file in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` containing

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

which did not work.

How to make those keys work; is it a problem with acpi?

Comment: Have you tried kernel parameter `i915.enable_dpcd_backlight` (from [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/clevo-laptop-lcd-and-keyboard-backlight/39028/16))?

Comment: @Freddy tried it now, no changes.

Comment: It's the Clevo N85_87HP6

Comment: Your laptop is discontinued by Clevo https://www.clevo.com.tw/clevo_pro.asp?lang=en and there's no Linux driver support from Sager http://sagernotebook.com/drivers.php?cat=697

Comment: Does that mean there's no way to control the brightness with those keys? This seems very strange to me...

Comment: The drivers which let those keys work were written for Windows, not Linux.